# How Can I make SQL sentences

Tags: java, android

I have a Data Base with Name and Password. When someone's enter both parameters I need to Select the correct Row on the DataBase. I know If i want select just the name I can do:

How Can I Select name and password? Thanks!

```
public void Register(View view){
    String User = usr.getText().toString();
    String Password = pass.getText().toString();
    if(User.isEmpty() && Password.isEmpty()) Toast.makeText(this, "You Must fill all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else{
        if(User.equals("admin") && Password.equals("admin")) ActivarActivityMenuAdministrador();
        else{
            AdminSQLiteOpenHelper adminsql = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "DBUsers",null,1 );
            SQLiteDatabase DB = adminsql.getWritableDatabase();

            Cursor fila = DB.rawQuery("select name, password from DBUsers where nombre=" + User, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing the password as plain text:

`DB.rawQuery("select name, password from DBUsers where name=" + User + " AND password=" + Password, null);`

**A side note:**
Never pass your arguments directly to SQL query, check [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89897/what-makes-an-android-application-vulnerable-to-sql-injection), instead you should perform the same as below:

`DB.rawQuery("SELECT name, password FROM DBUsers WHERE name = ? AND password = ?", new String[] {User, Password});`

Comment: Just a reminder that you're encouraging OP to use SQL code that is vulnerable to injection